# Is the word Concurrence synonymous with the word harmony

Tags: meaning, synonyms

recently I sat for an exam where I was asked this question -

Concurrence means all of the following except:

A. Agreement
B. Accord
C. Consensus
D. Coincidence
E. Harmony

What could be the correct answer ?
I opted for D. Coincidence. Was I right ?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: Yes I have, but I got no clear answer. The words agreement, accord & consensus are definitely synonymous with the word concurrence but there is confusion regarding coincidence & harmony. That's why I thought I should discuss it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the word Harmony is a synonym for Concurrence. 
But coincidence is synonym for Accord or Agreement.And Concurrence means Agreement too. So there is a conflict .

Comment: There isn't really a conflict.  All of the words are similar except coincidence, so the answer is D.

Comment: @Julia i have checked the synonyms for coincidence before posting the answer. Coincidence's synonym is Accord and Concurrence. The source is http://thesaurus.com/browse/coincidence

Comment: Yikes - I can see from that definition why you would think your answer is OK.  The thesaurus is not always as useful as a dictionary.  Take a look at this:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coincidence

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. Coincidence is something that happens accidentally. Without your knowledge.